# An variation of "Lk" in simplicial complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

Let $\mathcal S$ be a simplicial complex. For a simplex $S \in \mathcal S$, we have the closure, the star and the link

$\operatorname{Cl} S := \{ F \in \mathcal S : F \leq S \}$

$\operatorname{St} S := \{ T \in \mathcal S : S \leq T \}$

$\operatorname{Lk} S := \operatorname{Cl}\operatorname{St} S - \operatorname{St} \operatorname{Cl} S = \{ T \in \mathcal S : S \cap T = \emptyset \}$

We observe that $\operatorname{Lk} S$ is a subcomplex of $\operatorname{Cl}\operatorname{St}S$. I am interested in another subcomplex

$\operatorname{Lk}^\ast S := \{ T \in \mathcal S : S \nleq T \}$

What is known about this complex? Does it have a name?

Comment: I think for the closure you meant $\operatorname{Cl}S:=\{F\in\mathcal S\mid F\leq S\}$.

Comment: @StefanH.: Yes, thanks.